# How can I wrap a 3D array of a primitive type in an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have the following code and i am trying to wrap the 3D array of integers in an NSArray because i cannot return multidimensional arrays in C. Can anyone suggest how i could achieve it an a way that allows for easy access to the arrays after the function is returned?

```
-(NSArray *) Foo{
    int array[2][[self getWidth]][[self getHeight]];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self getWidth]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < [self getHeight]; j++) {
            // get th values for current position
            tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self convertAtPoint:i withYValue:j]];
             x = (int) [tmp objectAtIndex:0];
             y = (int) [tmp objectAtIndex:1];
             array[0][i][j] = x;
             array[1][i][j] = y;
        }
    }

    // How can i put the 3D array into a NSArray?
    NSArray *returnArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return returnArr;
}
```

Comment: You could return a multidimensional array if you allocated it on the heap using `malloc`.  If you want to store it in an `NSArray` you can flatten the data and store it in one dimension.  The way you'd do this depends if you want column-major or row-major ordering but one approach is `index = HEIGHT*WIDTH*z + WIDTH*y + x`.

Comment: Note: You can't store unboxed `int`s in an `NSArray` like this. `NSArray` holds Objective-C objects only, so if you want to store `int`s in one, you would wrap them in `NSNumber` instances.

Comment: Even so, would it be possible to wrap them in 3 dimensions after i stored them as NSNumbers?

Comment: Maybe you are better off by creating your own wrapper object for your threedimensional array. Other than that you can put `NSArray`s into `NSArray`s and finally NSNumber into the last array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using NSArray and reverted to a C array using malloc to allocate the space necessary for the array.

Comment: That works fine, of course, but if you want some of the niceties of Objective-C (e.g. memory management), you could return an `NSData` or `NSMutableData` holding the C array.